# symbols in `child()` is skipped: Pyrebase for python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) to push data into my firebase database. 
there is no issues when I push data normally. But issues arises with special symbols in child name.
For example

```
db.child("users").child("+91xxxxx")push(value, user['idToken'])
```

will set the child key as "91xxxx"
the `+` symbol is getting omitted. 
Is there any way to fix this

NB
This is not an issue with firebase. It maybe the pyrebase or the request which omits the data. I have successfully pushed the same values from android app. I am even not able to fetch datas pushed from android because the child has a key that starts with '+'

[image: screenshot of database]

Comment: @OluwafemiSule that describes about the characters not allowed in firebase. But I am able to push the same data from android. I have values in my firebase db. the '+' symbol is getting omitted. I am unable to fetch data too. This is the issue with pyrebase or api

Comment: Removed the duplicate flag. Investigating issues with pyrebase

Comment: @OluwafemiSule thanks

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I just got a solution. posted as answer. I wish to thank you for sparing time for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got an answer after reporting to github
https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/187#issuecomment-315940379

for python 2 it is

```
urllib.pathname2url('+91')
```

and for python 3 it is

```
urllib.parse.quote_plus("+91")
```

thanks for everyone